# Spring Boot http message converter serialize null sometimes

Tags: json, spring-boot, gson, http-message-converter

In Spring boot, is it possible to have many different versions of gson or Jackson http converters and use them dynamically whenever I need a specific type of data format?

Comment: Hi Kingj, could you please provide more information about what you want to do? for example your `Converter`, `Objects that you need to serialize as null or not dinamically` codes?

Comment: One of the reason why its null is , its not able to parse the object and throws an exception which you caught and supress ( may not be intentional). Add @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true) on top of your class

Comment: @Kingj done, I added an answer that you might implement it.

Comment: Sometimes you want to serialize nulls for the same entities or these are different entities?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create two beans for `GsonHttpMessageConverter` the first one with settings by default and second one with setting for serializing nulls by following way:

```
@Bean
public GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonHttpMessageConverter() {
    return buildGsonHttpMessageConverter(MapperUtil.getGsonInstance());
}

@Bean
public GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonHttpMessageConverterWithNulls() {
    return buildGsonHttpMessageConverter(MapperUtil.getGsonInstanceSerializeNulls());
}

private GsonHttpMessageConverter buildGsonHttpMessageConverter(final Gson gson) {
    final GsonHttpMessageConverter converter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setGson(gson);
    return converter;
}
```

And when you want to use one of them then call `@Qualifier("someBean")` annotation. by following way:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("gsonHttpMessageConverter")
GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonHttpMessageConverter;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("gsonHttpMessageConverterWithNulls")
GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonHttpMessageConverterWithNulls;
```

Comment: OK, if this answer solved your question, please mark as answer so that other persons can be helped.